# How to make a custom Authentication in Blazor

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor

**Hello**
l
I am stuck with this problem.
I am building a blazor server side page. I am have a custom login form where I call my api to check if the user login attempt was successful.
**This is my login form**
[image]

After a successful login, the user is redirected to another page. On this page, the navMenu is supposed to change.

I already understand that I need to override my AuthenticationStateProvider. But I dont understand how this works.

When the user inputs his informations a new object named user is created

```
namespace AdminFrontend.Services
{
    public class User
    {
        //"email" & "password" must be lowercase because the json 
   needs small initial letters
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string mobilenumber { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{email}: {password}: {mobilenumber}:  {service}";
        }
    }
}
```

How can i authorize the user after he logged in to see everything in the
`<Authorized>` Tag.

If you need some more informations let me know :D
Thanks for all answers

Comment: Why do you need to serialize your `User` object to json? Your solution seems to be blazor webassembly hosted where you have the wasm client and a server that is a web api. With this setup is not easy to setup authentication and authorization. I can provide you with a boilerplate project that uses your `User` object if you want which has this already setup including Entity Framework and you can go ahead and implement your pages and logic and learn from it how the authentication and authorization works.

Answer (score 3):

First all info i will post it's based on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#implement-a-custom-authenticationstateprovider)

**AuthenticationStateProvider** : Blazor has a built-in service called AuthenticationStateProvider service which obtains authentication state data from ASP.NET Core's and is used by AuthorizeView component and CascadingAuthenticationState component to get the authentication state. So based on that, we need to modify the core one to create or own authentication state, that inherits from main one (to get access to their main functionalities) so we need to do the following:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
     public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider()
     {
         //Anonymous User
         var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
         {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "0"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Anonymous"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Anonymous")
         }, null);

         this.CurrentUser = ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
     }

     private ClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser { get; set; }
     //Set Claims
     private ClaimsPrincipal GetUserClaim(string userName, string id, string role)
     {
         var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
         {
             new Claim(ClaimTypes. Sid, id),
             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)
         }, "Authentication type");
         return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
     }    

    //Principal function to use (to get the user with AuthenticationState.User)
    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var task = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.CurrentUser));
        return task;
    }

    public Task<AuthenticationState> ChangeUserClaim(string username, string id, string role)
    {
        this.CurrentUser = this.GetUser(username, id, role);
        var task = this.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        this.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(task);
        return task;
    }
}
```

Now with our custom Provider we need to add it on our startup.cs//program.cs (net 5 vs net 6)

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

And finally you can use  and  on your view! just remember to add this on the razor pages

```
[CascadingParameter] public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthTask { get; set; }

[Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider AuthState { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hey i tried you soulution but i get some errors. One is that "ClaimsPrincipal" cannot be used as a Methode and the other is that CustomAuthStateProvider dose not contain a definition for GetUser